# Многомерный массив TS,JS,REACT

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, typescript

Есть массив данных типа

```
Patient{
name:string,
birthDay: string,
groupId:number,
gender:string,
healthGroup:string
.....
}
```

хочу создать массив, в котором бы в качестве ключа выступали бы год рождения и ID группы
по типу:

```
[
0:{
  groupId:59,
  data:[
      0:[
        {
          birthYear:2004,
          data:[0:Patient,1:Patient,....]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Или может у кого есть идея по лучше, в общем мне нужно создать таблицу
Таблица:

[image: Таблица]

[image: Таблица]

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: с сервера получаю список пациентов и необходимо создать таблицу согласно картинке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте этот код. Я решила делать не массивы, а объекты. И не стала складывать пациентов, а просто подсчитала их. Вы можете получившийся объект пропустить через for in или с помощью map/lodash, к примеру.

```
enum Gender {
   M = 'm',
   W = 'w',
}
enum HealthGroup {
   D1 = 'd1',
   D2 = 'd2',
}
type Result = {
   [groupId: number]: {
     [year: number]: {
       [Gender.M]: number,
       [Gender.W]: number,
       [HealthGroup.D1]: number,
       [HealthGroup.D2]: number,
     },
   },
};

const data = [
  { groupId: 1, year: 2009, gender: Gender.M, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D1 },
  { groupId: 1, year: 2009, gender: Gender.W, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D2 },
  { groupId: 2, year: 2002, gender: Gender.M, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D1 },
  { groupId: 1, year: 2008, gender: Gender.W, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D2 },
  { groupId: 1, year: 2008, gender: Gender.M, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D1 },
  { groupId: 1, year: 2008, gender: Gender.M, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D2 },
  { groupId: 1, year: 2009, gender: Gender.W, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D2 },
  { groupId: 2, year: 2001, gender: Gender.M, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D1 },
  { groupId: 1, year: 2008, gender: Gender.W, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D1 },
  { groupId: 2, year: 2001, gender: Gender.W, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D2 },
  { groupId: 2, year: 2001, gender: Gender.M, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D1 },
  { groupId: 1, year: 2009, gender: Gender.W, healthGroup: HealthGroup.D2 },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, patient) => {
  acc[patient.groupId] = {
    ...acc[patient.groupId],
    [patient.year]: {
       ...acc[patient.groupId]?.[patient.year],
       [patient.gender]: (acc[patient.groupId]?.[patient.year]?.[patient.gender] || 0) + 1,
       [patient.healthGroup]: (acc[patient.groupId]?.[patient.year]?.[patient.healthGroup] || 0) + 1,
     },
   };
   return acc;
}, {} as Result);

console.log(result);
```